# docker jsbundling-rails: Command build failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Hello I'm learning docker and I faced this error while testing it locally
i used this code to build this app i used also some JavaScript code

```
rails new icb --main --database=postgresql -c=bootstrap
```

```
banstein@DESKTOP-I54N512:~/Projects/icb$ docker-compose build
[+] Building 4.2s (12/12) FINISHED                                                    
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.0                    1.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 7.59kB                                              0.0s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:3.2.0@sha256:f2ec40227806aaab47e928f2e0ea  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apt-get update -qq &&     apt-get install -y build-essenti  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/8] WORKDIR /rails                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/8] COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [5/8] RUN bundle install                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [6/8] COPY . .                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [7/8] RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile app/ lib/         0.0s
 => ERROR [8/8] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile  3.1s
------
 > [8/8] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile:
#0 3.016 Parsing scenario file install
#0 3.017 ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'
#0 3.027 rails aborted!
#0 3.027 jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
#0 3.027 
#0 3.027 Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => javascript:build
#0 3.027 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your image doesn't have yarn installed. The error messages are telling you where to look right here:

```rb
> [8/8] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile:
#0 3.016 Parsing scenario file install
#0 3.017 ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'
#0 3.027 rails aborted!
#0 3.027 jsbundling-rails: Command build failed, ensure yarn is installed and `yarn build` runs without errors
```

It happens when this line is executed: `RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 bundle exec rails assets:precompile:`

Remove the extra colon you have after precompile. Then modify your dockerfile to ensure yarn is installed before you get to the asset precompile step.